# How can I make the opencv function WaitKey() wait for less than one millisecond?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm making a maze solver program that shows the BFS in action. But it takes a long time to execute when it waits for 1 millisecond before adding a new point on the image to the queue. However, it is important for me that I can see the BFS search work, in other words: I want there to be **some** delay. So I wondered if there is any way to make the WaitKey function wait for a shorter time, maybe 0.01 ms. I can't make it so that the program only waits for keypresses every 20 or so itirations, because then the "animation" would skip a lot of points.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: No, you can't. However, it doesn't make much sense. I don't think your eyes will notice any difference at 10000 Hz. That is, the problem is not waiting for 1 ms, but something else is slowing down your program, and wait for less than 1 ms won't help

Comment: My program uses a 400x400 picture as input for the maze. When I run the BFS without displaying the image it takes about 1 second. So the hold up is the fact that the program waits 1 millisecond before adding a new element to the queue, so I can display the frame.

Comment: drawing is probably much more expensive than showing... hard to tell without seeing some code.

Comment: Edited the post, disregard the norwegian comments.

Comment: I can't investigate further now, but the code will help a lot. You can also add your maze image.

Comment: I fixed it by creating the following code:   
`if (counter > 50) {`  
     `cv::namedWindow("Display window",   CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);`     
     `cv::imshow("Display window", img);`   
     `cv::waitKey(1);`   
     `counter = 0;`   
`}`   
`counter++;'`

Comment: waitKey(1) does not guarantee to only wait 1 ms. On windows OS, it will mostly be something like 5-15 ms.

Comment: I solved issues with this using threads - may not apply to your case however...

Comment: I hate to be a whiner, but stuff like this right here are how library authors lose a lot of valuable customers who make high performance things by implementing poorly thought out APIs like this. They could have made it so that a negative integer delay would be treated as infinite, instead of 0. Instead, there is no distinction, and we get this forced sleeping behavior.